# rauth with Flask returns 404 on all requests

Tags: python, api, flask, python-requests, rauth

Running into an issue where no requests from OAuth2Session object are being fulfilled.
`curl GET "https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/top/artists" -H "Authorization: Bearer <access_token returned from OAuth2Session.access_token within failing program below>` works just fine.

The same session that returned that access token returns a 404 on:
`session.get('/me/top/artists')` [expected, as `Authorization: Bearer <access_token>` is not passed]
`session.request('GET', '/me/top/artists')` [reading source seems to imply the Bearer Authorization header is included by default]

Larger code snippet [you'll notice it looks very similar to some of the examples]:

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, render_template, url_for
from rauth.service import OAuth2Service
from app import app
import os

spotify = OAuth2Service(name='spotify',
    authorize_url=AUTH_URL,
    access_token_url=TOKEN_URL,
    client_id=os.getenv('SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID'),
    client_secret=os.getenv('SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    base_url='https://api.spotify.com/v1')

@app.route('/authorize')
def authorize():
    redirect_uri = url_for('authorized', _external=True)
    params = {'response_type': 'code', 'redirect_uri': redirect_uri, 'scope': 'user-top-read'}

    return redirect(spotify.get_authorize_url(**params))

@app.route('/authorized')
def authorized():
    if not 'code' in request.args:
        flash('You did not authorize the request')
        return redirect(url_for('welcome'))

    redirect_uri = url_for('authorized', _external=True)

    data = {'grant_type': 'authorization_code', 'code': request.args['code'], 'redirect_uri': redirect_uri}

    def byte_decoder(byte_load):
        return json.loads(byte_load.decode())

    session = spotify.get_auth_session(data=data, decoder=byte_decoder)

    # this is where I am trying the requests

    return redirect(url_for('web'))
```

`AUTH_URL` and `TOKEN_URL` replace links because I don't have 10 reputation to post > 2 links.